# Trying to find a CSS or javascript script that automatically blurs/blackens images until hovered over or clicked on

Tags: javascript, css

trying to find a CSS or javascript script to automatically make images black or just blurred until hovered over or clicked on for discord.

Comment: Yes, that’s possible with [CSS filters](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), [mix blend modes](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode), and related properties, as well as `:hover` and transitions. What is your question? What do you mean by “for Discord”?

Comment: The social platform for talking with people, im using an API tweaker called betterdiscord to change certain stuff and wanted to have a script thatll automatically blur images above a certain size so i dont have to see every single image that pops up in case its nsfw

Answer (score 3):

Will this work? Just a simple css solution.

This is the snippet:

```css
img {
  filter: blur(5px) brightness(60%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s filter ease;
}

img:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/101/253/non_2x/vector-free-abstract-background-1.jpg" alt="abstract image" />
```

Comment: yes it works, thank you, but is it also possible to filter the blurring to only images above a certain size? like 500px by 500px?

Comment: You need to use javascript for that.

Comment: im learning JS right now anyway ima just put this off till im more experienced thank you kind sir

Comment: @ihaveaskimask, My pleasure :)